# "ParsePI: PI php never end" when trying to run a new unit test

Tags: php, xml, phpunit

I have created a unit test and used the following command to run the test:

```
bin/phpunit -c path/to/DocumentDuplicateControllerTest.php
```

... and I find that I get this output:

> ParsePI: PI php never end ...
>
> Start tag expected, '<' not found

Unfortunately, turning off the `-c` flag is not an option, as the command runs with that flag during a Jenkins job.

Can someone make a suggestion about how to fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`-c` is a command line option to specify a configuration file:

```
-c|--configuration <file>   Read configuration from XML file.
```

It requires a file as the next parameter. This file has to be a PHPUnit XML configuration file.

You provide an PHP file. I imagine it starts with `<?php` but has no closing `?>`. The XML parser treats the `<?php` as the start of an XML processing instruction, it is not closed hence the error message.

You should create and specify an `phpunit.xml`